# Can you make a pillager farm with snow blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Pillagers can spawn on snow blocks due to 1.18, is it possible to make a pillager farm with snow blocks? I was thinking of making it like 50x50 or 100x100 so it is more like a snowy biome, would that work or do pillagers spawn on snow blocks only naturally generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what mojang has provided us with they can now spawn on snowblocks therefore pillagers can spawn on natural and unatural snow blocks. So yes it can be done.